# Document css not applied to ngDialog template

Tags: angularjs

used ngtemplate below:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="attach_account_template">
  <div id="attach_account_div" ng-controller="Opportunity_Controller" style="width:250px">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="account_name" style="width:200px;height:35px" />
    <input id="btn_account" type="button" style="margin-left:10px;height:35px;width:50px" value="GO" />
  </div>
</script>
```

opened ng-dialog on the ng-click of a hyperlink:

```
$scope.attach_account = function () {
    //attach_account_template
    ngDialog.open({ template: 'attach_account_template', scope: $scope });
};
```

Expecting that the document css will be applied to the template but it hasn't.
how can I make document css apply to the ng-template?

Answer (score 0):

```
ngDialog.open({
            template: ‘url’,
            className:’cssStyle’,
            scope: $scope,  
            showClose: false,
            overlay: true,
            closeByEscape: false,
        });
```

Your need to use the ClassName with attribute like  "className: 'ngdialog-theme-default'" to get things resolved